# how to define a pk for models in django-tables 2 ? isn't it an automated?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-tables2

I've used django-table2 to render a patients list entered by users however I'm getting a value error for unknown reason to me:
Failed lookup for key [Patient] in , when resolving the accessor Patient.pk

here's my tables.py

```
class PatientTable(tables.Table):

FirstName = tables.Column(linkify=("PatientDetailView", {"pk": tables.A("Patient.pk")}))
LastName = tables.Column(linkify=("PatientDetailView", {"pk": tables.A("Patient.pk")}))
Telephone_no = tables.Column(linkify=("PatientDetailView", {"pk": tables.A("Patient.pk")}))

class Meta:
    model = Patient
    # attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-hover'}
    exclude = ("user", "Notes", "Address")
    template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

and here's my view function in the views.py

```
def Patients_list(request):
    table = PatientTable(Patient.objects.filter(user=request.user))

    return render(request, 'accounts/patients_list.html',{
    'table' : table
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
{"pk": tables.A("Patient.pk")}
```

to :

```
{"pk": tables.A("pk")}
```

and it worked i don't know why i had written it that way.